# I have a problem with ListView when saving names

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview with First Name, Last Name, User ID... 
And to add a user I use textboxes and a add button, and heres where the problem comes. 
StreamWriter saves the "textboxes" not the "ListView Items", so if I leave the textboxes empty it stores a blank line in my file(.txt). 
How can I make so the streamwriter saves the ListView items instead? 
Hope it makes sense :D

Code:

```
  private void buttonAddNewUser_Click (object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (firstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty (lastName) || 
              string.IsNullOrEmpty (userID)) return;
        {
            ListViewItem dataItems = new ListViewItem (firstName);
            dataItems.SubItems.Add (lastName);
            dataItems.SubItems.Add (userID);
            listView1.Items.Add (dataItems);
        }

    }

    private void btnSaveToFile_Click (object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists (@"D:\PersonsSaved.txt"))
        {
            string fullName = firstName + "," + lastName + "," + userID;
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter (@"D:\PersonsSaved.txt" , true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine (fullName);

                MessageBox.Show ("User(s) has been saved!");

            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load (object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileLocation = @"D:\PersonsSaved.txt";
        List<string> userData = File.ReadAllLines (fileLocation).ToList ();

        foreach (var item in userData)
        {
            string[ ] items = item.Split (new char[ ] { ',' });
            listView1.Items.Add (new ListViewItem (items));
        }


    }

    private void textBoxFirstName_TextChanged (object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        firstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
    }

    private void textBoxLastName_TextChanged (object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        lastName = textBoxLastName.Text;
    }

    private void textBoxUserID_TextChanged (object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        userID = textBoxUserID.Text;
    }
```

Comment: You need to save each item in the listview: `foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){ // Write to file }`

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Johnny

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hello, I have been experimenting with what you gave me. But it doesn't end up like I want it. So I made something else, but in the text file it ends up like this: ListViewItem: {firstname}, ListViewSubItem: {lastname}, ListViewSubItem: {userID}. Anyway to remove the "listviewitem"

Comment: One last thing, i forgot to add that if i use your way the result will be: ListViewItem: {firstname} only.Maybe I don't understand.

Comment: You need to use the `Text` field. I have typed up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each item in the listview and save it:

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\PersonsSaved.txt", true))
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            string fullName = $"{item.Text},{item.SubItems[1].Text},{item.SubItems[2].Text}";
            writer.WriteLine(fullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logic to see what is in the boxes

```
private void btnSaveToFile_Click (object sender , EventArgs e)
{
  if (File.Exists (@"D:\PersonsSaved.txt"))
  {
    if (firstName.Length + lastName.Length + userID.Length > 0)
    {
      string fullName = firstName + "," + lastName + "," + userID;
      using (var writer = new StreamWriter (@"D:\PersonsSaved.txt" , true))
      {
        writer.WriteLine (fullName);

        MessageBox.Show ("User(s) has been saved!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```